# Create a shortcode to display related posts (posts in the same category) in the sidebar

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to display in the article sidebar (in wordpress) a list of 5 recent articles from that category to which it belongs. I'm using the code below to (using a shortcode) show the 5 posts (from category 62 in this case). Is there a way to write this code in functions.php so that it is optimised, and I don't have to rewrite everything for each new category?

```
 /** 
  * function to add recent posts widget 
  */ 
function wpcat_postsbycategory_musculacao() {
 // the query
 $the_query = new WP_Query( array( 'cat' => '62', 'posts_per_page' => 5 ) ); 
 // The Loop
 if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
     $string .= '<ul class="postsbytag widget_recent_entries">';
     while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
         $the_query->the_post();
             if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
             $string .= '<li>';
             $string .= '<a href="' . get_the_permalink() .'" rel="bookmark">' . get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id, array( 80, 80) ) . get_the_title() .'</a></li>';
             } else { 
             // if no featured image is found
             $string .= '<li><a href="' . get_the_permalink() .'" rel="bookmark">' . get_the_title() .'</a></li>';
             }
             }
     } else {
     // no posts found
 }
 $string .= '</ul>';
 return $string;
 /* Restore original Post Data */
 wp_reset_postdata();
 }
 // Add a shortcode
 add_shortcode('categoryposts-musculacao', 'wpcat_postsbycategory_musculacao');
 
 /** 
  * function to change search widget placeholder 
  */
 function db_search_form_placeholder( $html ) {
        $html = str_replace( 'placeholder="Pesquisar ', 'placeholder="Buscar ', $html );
        return $html;
}
add_filter( 'get_search_form', 'db_search_form_placeholder' );
```

Comment: Posts can have multiple categories in Wordpress, so it depends on what you want to do about that. My answer below gives you different ways to do this depending on how you want to do it. Let me know how you get on with those!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The complication here is that in WP a post can have multiple categories. You need to decide how to handle that - get from all categories, or if you only want to show posts from one category, how do you choose which?

I've given a few answers below depending on how you want to handle that.

**1. Get posts in *any* of the categories of the current post**

As posts can have multiple categories, you can get all of the ids and use this to query for posts that are in *any* of those categories:

```
// 1. get the categories for the current post
global $post;
$post_categories = get_the_category( $post->ID );

// 2. Create an array of the ids of all the categories for this post
$categoryids = array(); 
foreach ($post_categories as $category)
    $categoryids[] = $category->term_id;

// 3. use the array of ids in your WP_Query to get posts in any of these categories
$the_query = new WP_Query( array( 'cat' => implode(",",$categoryids), 'posts_per_page' => 5 ) );
```

**1a. Get posts in *any* of the categories but *not* their children**

Note `cat` will include children of those category ids. If you want to include those exact categories only and not children, use `category__in` instead of `cat`:

```
$the_query = new WP_Query( array('category__in' => $categoryids, 'posts_per_page' => 5) );
```

**2. Get posts that have *all* of the categories of the current post**

If you want posts that have all the same categories as the current one, this is done in the same way as above, except we use `category__and` instead of `cat` (Note that this does *not* include children of those categories) :

```
$the_query = new WP_Query( array('category__in' => $categoryids, 'posts_per_page' => 5) );
```

**3. If you know your post will only have one category**

If you know you only have one category per post, then you can just use the first element from the category array:

```
// 1. Just use the id of the first category
$categoryid = $post_categories[0]->term_id;
$the_query = new WP_Query( array( 'cat' => $categoryid, 'posts_per_page' => 5 ) );
```

**4. Pass the category into the shortcode**

If you want to specify which category to show, you can pass the category id into the shortcode, letting you choose whichever category you want. (FYI you can also get it to work with slug instead of id, which might be a bit more user-friendly)

Your shortcode is currently used like this, I assume:

```
[categoryposts-musculacao]
```

We can change the function so you can pass the category like this:

```
[categoryposts-musculacao category=62]
```

Shortcode function can accept an `$attributes` argument that has the information or "attributes" we're adding to the shortcode, e.g. `category`. We use this to get the category passed in as a variable called `$category` and then just use it instead of the hardcoded value in the rest of your function.

```
// 1. include the $attributes argument
function wpcat_postsbycategory_musculacao(  $attributes ) {
    // 2. get the value passed in as category - this will save it into a variable called `$category`
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'category' => ''
    ), $attributes ) );

    // 3. if there is no category don't do anything (or sohw a message or whatever you want
    if (!$category) return "";

    // 4. Now just use your variable instead of the hardcoded value in the rest of the code
     $the_query = new WP_Query( array( 'cat' => $category, 'posts_per_page' => 5 ) ); 
 
    // do the rest of your stuff!
}
```

Reference: [Wordpress Codex Shortcode API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API)

**4a. Pass the category into the shortcode by slug**

If you want the `category` attribute in your shortcode to work with a slug instead of the id, you just need to change `WP_Query` to use `category_name` instead of `cat`:

```
$the_query = new WP_Query( array( 'category_name' => $category, 'posts_per_page' => 5 ) );
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your help. I used the code below, it worked using category ID but not with category name or slug.

Comment: No, you would to adapt it slightly to work with the name or slug. Did you want to be able to do it like that?

Comment: `/** 
  * function to add post list widget with categry posts
  */ 
// 1. include the $attributes argument
function wpcat_postslistbycategory(  $attributes ) {
    // 2. get the value passed in as category - this will save it into a variable called `$category`
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'category' => ''
    ), $attributes ) );
    // 3. if there is no category don't do anything (or sohw a message or whatever you want
    if (!$category) return "";
    // 4. Now just use your variable instead of the hardcoded value in the rest of the code`

Comment: `$the_query = new WP_Query( array( 'cat' => $category, 'posts_per_page' => 5 ) ); 
 
    // do the rest of your stuff!
 // The Loop
 if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
     $string .= '<ul class="postsbytag widget_recent_entries">';
     while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
         $the_query->the_post();
             if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
             $string .= '<li>';
             $string .= '<a href="' . get_the_permalink() .'" rel="bookmark">' . `

Comment: `get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id, array( 80, 80) ) . get_the_title() .'</a></li>';
             } else { 
             // if no featured image is found
             $string .= '<li><a href="' . get_the_permalink() .'" rel="bookmark">' . get_the_title() .'</a></li>';
             }
             }
     } else {
     // no posts found
 }
 $string .= '</ul>';
 return $string;
 /* Restore original Post Data */
 wp_reset_postdata();
 }
 // Add a shortcode
 add_shortcode('postlistbycategory', 'wpcat_postslistbycategory');`

Comment: Hi, I guess that it is not necessary, unless it's a very simple modification to make. Thanks

Comment: No, not difficult, I've updated the answer (see 4a. at the end). If my answer helped, you can accept it to mark your question as solved and also let other users with similar questions know that this could help them too!